# "Set-Cookie" header item in response is damaged?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7

I can`t resolve big problem for me:

The web-server send to client on WP7 the "Set-Cookie" header like this:

`.AUTOINDEXAUTH=; expires=Mon, 11-Oct-1999 22:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly     .AUTOINDEXAUTH=EAD9393175E92DDD04C88DDE022A56048FD816971197E1A448C16E80EE551DE1B4ECD91658D72BD6092841C58161D25B56FB81D373D85DB113D8F961DE649ABBAA35753958A210106206C9A172977CA0993FCECCB70D28DAA9928DAD349577BACC119432C8164C68EF9F96B59472651F01CE36357A8CA09213FB37BA16724820C1EF4719E9F7592F8F2F21107C6013C9; path=/; HttpOnly`

But in response header on client (`HttpWebResponse.Hedaders`) in "Set-Cookie" only this string:

```
.AUTOINDEXAUTH=; expires=Mon, 11-Oct-1999 22:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Any body know why?

Comment: Have you tried http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ to capture what the request actually contains? What is your web server? IIS?

Comment: Yes, server is IIS.
The site is on https.
In fiddler when I check "capture https" client app not work.

Answer (score 0):

Two cookies with the same domain, name and path are considered equal, and only one of these values is used.

See http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt (chapter 4.3.3)

Comment: And same blackberry application receive 2 "set-cookie' headers: One with empty ".AUTOINDEXAUTH="   and second: ".AUTOINDEXAUTH=" whith data. I think that WP7 HttpWebResponse class not correctly parse this header.

Comment: The duplicate cookie is apparently already filtered out when you read the `HttpWebResponse.Headers`. Is your code relying on receiving two values for one and the same cookie?

Comment: Yes, I need to receive ".AUTOINDEXAUTH=" cookie with value.